# Error in Eclipse connecting to respository and installing ADT Plugin on Windows 8

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, adt, installation

I have recently updated to Windows 8 (don't ask why as it has become more hassle than it is worth!)

Since doing so, my Eclipse and ADT Plugin stopped working. So I downloaded a Eclipse Classic again and tried to download the ADT Plugin with no luck. (note: none of the downloads from Eclipse drop down menu are possible when selected)

I keep getting the following error message when trying to connect to the online repository:
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml/content.xml.
Cannot assign requested address: connect

When trying to add the plugin through ZIP file, I get through and get stuck with the following error:
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395)

Stuck and need some advice! I have the latest version of the Android SDK and have updated to the latest version of Java Run-time & JDK

Answer (score 3):

Having the exactly same problem like yours. Managed to fix it by changing https to http

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively ADT plugin can be installed from archive. Please see "Troubleshooting ADT Installation" part from below link for more details.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 2):

From the official documentation:

> If Eclipse can not find the remote update site containing the ADT plugin, try changing the remote site URL to use http, rather than https. That is, set the Location for the remote site to

**http://** dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

This  solved it for me.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please **Accept this answer as correct.**

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I run Eclipse with XP SP3 compability and installed ADT from an archive.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly download the package from http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-XX.X.X.zip
(Replace X with the revision number). Install it and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong URL for the update site. It is only https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/, while you probably appended "site.xml" in the dialog, judging by your error message.

Answer (score 0):

1.download latest version of ADT, current ADT-23.0.2.zip (*)
2.At Eclipse > Help > Install new software... > Uncheck Contact all update sites during install to find required software (bottom, last preference) in order to avoid any unwanted delays during install.
3.Same screen (top) Click Add > Archive > select downloaded ADT-X.X.X.zip > follow on screen installation steps.

(*) Previous versions:

ADT-23.0.0.zip

ADT-22.6.0.zip | ADT-22.6.1.zip | ADT-22.6.2.zip | ADT-22.6.3.zip

ADT-22.3.0.zip

ADT-22.2.1.zip

ADT-22.0.0.zip | ADT-22.0.1.zip | ADT-22.0.5.zip

ADT-21.1.0.zip